# jQuery src adds strange class on IMGs

Tags: jquery, class

I have noticed, that with:

```
<img id="smth" src="#" />
...........
...........
...........
$("#smth").src = ".....";
```

and strange class is added to `img` element:

[image]

(this doesnt happen if i dont execute that).
 Any thoughts?

Comment: `$("#element").get(0).src`

Comment: What was the src of element before you assigned the value to it, what was the value and what was the src after assinging the value?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: i have inserted the initial `img` element in my question. But why only class appears, if it is object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#element")
```

returns an jquery object representing the elements matching the selector. In this case it is an representing a single element. When you intend to set its `src` like this

```
$("#element").src = ".....";
```

you are actually trying to set the `src` attribute of that jquery object. Instead of that, there are several possible solutions. Examples:

**attr**

```
$("#element").attr("src", ".....");
```

**prop**

```
$("#element").prop("src", ".....");
```

**element of array**

```
$("#element")[0].src = ".....";
```

**get**

```
$("#element").get(0).src = ".....";
```

Comment: But why only class appears, if it is object?

Comment: @tazotodua, it seems to be a key which might differentiate elements represented by the jQuery object under the hood. However, this is just an educated guess. The actual behavior shown in the question was unknown for me as well